# image to left of placeholder in styled.input react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input, styled-components

i am trying to achieve this design:
[goalimg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC0aO.png)

and this is what i have so far: [currentimg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brnQz.png)

I need to have the search icon display to the left of the placeholder text in this input.
I am using a styled input component in react javascript.
This is my CSS style for the input:

```
const SearchBar = styled.input`
color: #000000;
margin-top: 20px;
background: #F2F2F7;
padding-left: 35.33px;
border-radius: 50px;
height: 30px;

border: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.gray2};
padding-top: 7px;
padding-bottom: 7px;
margin-left: 14px;
margin-right: 14px;
outline-width: 1px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
```

`;

and this is in the render() method:

`<SearchBar placeholder="Search Chats"></SearchBar>`

How can I place the image in the input to the left of the placeholder text?

Comment: look at using css 'position: absolute;' to place the icon on top of the input.

Comment: @JDavies how would I include the image though?

Comment: if you add to the <head> of your index.html (or where ever you are rendering your app to). 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`
then you can add `<i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>` to your react code. So long as you are online. you can access many icons here: [link](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/).

Comment: @JDavies ok I was able to do that, but where do I include <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> so that it is to the left of the placeholder text in my input bar?

Comment: Wrap both the input and icon in a div or span. Give the span `position: relative;` and then give the i `position: absolute;` `top: 0px;` `left: 0px;` adjust the top and left value to get the placement right. To make sure the icon is layered above the icon. Give the i a `z-index: 1;`

Comment: @JDavies this is what I have:<span style={{position: 'relative'}}>

                    <i style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: -1,
                    marginTop: '0px', marginLeft: '25px'}} 
                    className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                    
                    <SearchBar placeholder="Search Chats"></SearchBar>
                
                </span>      and it still isnt showing properly, the search icon isnt even showing now

Comment: a z-index of -1 will make it disappear. 0 is default, a higher z-index will mean it should be placed on a layer above. I will write as an answer below

Comment: @JDavies another question, how would I use the same code you put in the answer below but have the icon show on the other end of the input? So at the right end of the input?

Comment: change `left:` to `right:` to align from the right end of the span. you can also use negative values like `-10px`.  `position: absolute` positions the element relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element. In this case, the span

Comment: @JDavies got it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your index.html (or where ever you are rendering your app to) add to the head:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<div id="app"></div>
```

in your React file add:

```
 <span className='search-bar'>
    <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input></input>
 </span>
```

in your Css file add:

```
.search-bar { 
  position: relative;
  input { padding: 12px; }
  .fa-search { 
    position: absolute; 
    padding: 12px;
    top: 2px; 
    left: 5px; 
    z-index: 1; 
  }
}
```

or, instead of padding, you can use

```
.fa-search { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 2px; 
  left: 5px; 
  z-index: 1; 
}
```

Adjust the top & left value to position it exactly.

Plus any other styling to the input.

you can access many icons here: [link](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/)